# Using threads in an MVC desktop application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, model-view-controller

I am developing a C# desktop application (Windows Forms) with MVC and I want to use threads because I think it will provide me a more fluid interaction with the view to the final user, I will try to explain my best what I want.

I implemented MVC like this:

- View -> has several controls that trigger events, these events are
  subscribed by the controller
- Controller -> receives some information from these events and passes
  it to model by calling the adequate method, like this
  Program.model.methodX(data)
- Model -> processes the information and sends the data to the view by
  triggering events that are subscribed by the view so it can update
  itself

What the model actually does is communicate with a PLC to get some data from certain registers, while its doing this the view is freezed waiting for the reply.. I tried to implement threads in the model, because I think its the appropriate place for this, the problem is that I need to pass some information for the thread (number of registers etc) which is a problem because the thread wants a method that returns void and has no parameters (ThreadStart), and in the end send the data to the view by triggering an event which is a problem because it wants an object reference if it's a non-static method, field or property etc.. Is there any way I can achieve this or am I thinking all wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you have a couple of questions in there, but I will try to address them:

1. You can pass parameters to a thread but you need to use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) which allows the passing of an object.
2. In regards to passing data in and getting data back, you should probably look into using the [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and specifically the `StartNew` methods which will create a new `Task`.  You can pass lambdas, methods that take parameters, and functions which will return a result and then you can use the task object to wait for and retrieve the result.  For more info on threading including some insight into using the `TaskFactory` check out this link from Joseph Albahari on [threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx).  It is an excellent resource.

In the general sense there are numerous techniques for getting data in and out of a thread.  You can pass the `this` parameter in and then have access to all of its members, just remember that you are dealing with multiple threads and so need to be careful with reading/writing data.  If there is shared data you will need to protect it with some form of locking.  If you don't have to share the data while the thread is running, I would probably make a class to hold the data I need to pass that to the thread and do the same for the result.  Then you can just use the TaskFactory.StartNew to launch the task and pass the data in and use the result of the task to get the data back out.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the answer as it led me to solve the problem, I ended up using ParameterizedThreadStart passing in an object with the parameters I wanted and called the event afterwards inside the thread, not sure if it's the best way to do this but everything worked fine so thank you very much for your help and time.